# Sort devices by version and alphabetically and return all versions of that phone

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have the following table:

```
|  Device  | Version |
|--------------------|
| shamu    | 5.1     |
| h815     | 5.1     |
| bullhead | 4.2     |
| shamu    | 4.2     |
| h815     | 5.1.1   |
| h811     | 5.4     |
| surnia   | 5.10    |
| mido     | 4.2     |
```

And I know I can sort the versions with:

```
ORDER BY INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Version,".0.0.0"),".",4)) DESC
```

But I don't know how to group the devices so that ordered by version they have all it's versions, so that the table returned is:

```
|  Device  | Version |
|--------------------|
| surnia   | 5.10    |
| h811     | 5.4     |
| h815     | 5.1.1   |
| h815     | 5.1     |
| shamu    | 5.1     |
| shamu    | 4.2     |
| bullhead | 4.2     |
| mido     | 4.2     |
```

So you see that surnia has the biggest number, so it's first. h811 has 5.4, the second one. So it puts it after. h815 has the third one, so all h815 versions go sorted. And at the end you see that, with the same version, bullhead is before mido because it's alphabetically ordered

Comment: Using INET_ATON in this way is a hack (albeit one I advocate), so it has obvious limitations of which you need to be aware. That said, if you provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements, I've no doubt that someone will oblige you with an answer (- or even if you don't!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to join with a query that gets the maximum version for each device. Then you can order by that, then order by device and the specific version.

```
SELECT d.device, version
FROM devices AS d
JOIN (SELECT device, MAX(INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Version,".0.0.0"),".",4))) AS maxversion
      FROM devices
      GROUP BY device) AS m ON d.device = m.device
ORDER BY maxversion DESC, d.device, INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Version,".0.0.0"),".",4)) DESC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2892d4/1)